# Why does W1036 occur when using a variable assigned under the same immutable condition?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have to execute optional code lines at the start and at the end of a block of code.

```
procedure Test(const AInitializeFlag : Boolean);
var
  Flag : Integer;
begin
  if(AInitializeFlag) then
    Flag := 1;
  
  //...
    
  if(AInitializeFlag) then
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Flag));
end;
```

In this example case, even if I'm using the `Flag` variable only when I'm sure it has been initialized, the `W1036` occours on compiling:

> [dcc32 Warning] Unit1.pas(37): W1036 Variable 'Flag' might not have
> been initialized

Comment: The answer is: "because the compiler isn't smart enough". This is something that happens to me regularly. Every time I assign an (unnecessary) initial value and add a comment stating that it is there only to get rid of W1036.

Comment: In order to be able not to present this warning, the compiler would have to perform [data flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis#:~:text=Data%2Dflow%20analysis%20is%20a,to%20a%20variable%20might%20propagate.). It does not do this.